# Android VTS is not running on Android-Oreo 8.1

Tags: android, android-vts

Error when running Android VTS on Android-O (8.1) API level 27.

Can Someone help me what is wrong here.

Error Message:
Invocation failed:java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: None of the abi supported by this CTS build ('[armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a]') are supported by the device ('[x86]').

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, VTS which you have built/using is not proper.

$ . build/envsetup.sh
$ lunch aosp_`arm64`-userdebug
$ make vts -j
Use proper architecture as per your device requirements.

https://source.android.com/compatibility/vts/systems